# How to upload and preview the uploaded image using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

I have created the following web page:

```
...
<img alt="" src="images/frame.png" id="contact-image" />
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="PHPScripts/upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" id="browseContactImageButton" name="image"
           accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif"
           onchange="this.form.submit();" />
</form>
...
```

I want to be able to upload the the image to file system or database (haven't decided yet) and to be able to see the uploaded image in the `<img id="contact-image" />` immediately after the file has been uploaded, without reloading the page, i.e. using AJAX.

Can you show me the concept that I should follow? I know that I am making a mistake by calling the `PHPScripts/upload.php` on form submitting. My guess is that I should call some javascript function instead, but where do I go from there and what should that function look like? Thanks.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop/

Comment: Check this if it can help you http://codingbin.com/upload-image-with-ajax-and-preview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the best solution in my opinion. It doesn't involve jQuery and it provides AJAX-like functionality. Thank you to everyone who has put an effort in helping me resolve this. Cheers!

http://www.articlealley.com/article_573896_81.html

Answer (score 2):

With MVC or any other backend it's fairly simple. Let's assume you have a controller with the name UploadPicture. When the webserver has finished uploading the picture, you would simply make the server return json with the image path or whatever you need.

I would recommend using jQuery since it's an excellent framework to work with Javascript and has a good cross-browser support.

I've done this before and it was just like what I described above.

IF you happen to know the path and image name, then you wouldn't even need to return anything from the server. You would simply do with jQuery when the upload has finished:

```
$("#contact-image img").attr('src', 'http://PathToImage');
```

And you could use $.ajax to trigger when the submit has finished.

Reference on $.ajax - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Ajax upload

You can find explanations and examples it here:

http://www.zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [swfupload](http://swfupload.org)?

here is a [demo](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/index.htm) that uses php

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use the [YUI file upload](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/) or [JQuery plug](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuery-File-Upload) in for file upload. Once the file is upload you can retrieve the file path from the server and update using the JS on the client side.

```
var imgControl = document.getElementById('image');

imgControl.src = filePathFromServer;
```

And if you want to try something new **HTML5** ... i will suggest to have a look at [this demo](http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/DnD/).